# Vue 3: How to change specific sibling component's data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Say you have 3 components:

```
<Modal>
<Navbar>
<Hero>
```

Your `Modal` component has data saying whether it's open or not, along with the appropriate methods:

```
data() {
    return {
        active: false,
    }
},
methods: {
    open() {this.active = true},
    close() {this.active = false},
    switch() {this.active ? this.close(): this.open()}
}
```

and you want a link in your `Navbar` component to be able to open it:

```
template: 
/*html*/
`<nav class="navbar">
  <router-link :to="etc.">Home</router-link>
  <router-link :to="etc.">About</router-link>
  <a @click="openSiblingModalSomehow">Contact</a> <!-- This one -->
</nav>`
```

As well as the Call to Action button on your `Hero` component:

```
template:
/*html*/
`<div class="hero">
    <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    <button @click="openSiblingModelSomehow">Contact Me</button>
</div>`
```

Assuming you **DON'T** want a global property to access this... For example, what if you want more than one type of modal?:

```
<ContactModal>
<SignUpModal>
<OtherModal>
<Navbar>
<Hero>
```

and knowing that **the `Modal` also needs to be able to close itself**,

How would you trigger a specific sibling element / component to open the `Modal` (in this case, let's say `ContactModal`) using Vue 3?

I thought about using a variable on the App itself, but it seems a bit hectic to change a globalProperty only for a specific component with it's own data.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge at my project. My approach was to not use a `Boolean` property.

Step by step, first declare a empty string at the parent, that provides it for your modal boxes:

```
data() {
    return {
        active: ""
    }
}
```

Declare a method, that handles that string:

```
methods: {
    switchActive(string) {
      if (string) {
        this.active = string;
      }
      else {
        this.active = ""
      }
    }
}
```

This would be one of your modal components:

```
<template>
  <Dialog header="Header" footer="Footer" :visible="checkActive">
    I am the modal dialog.
    <button @click="this.$emit('close')">Close Me</button>
  </Dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "modal-123",
  props: {
    active: String
  },
  computed: {
    checkActive() {
      return this.active === this.$options.name;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And call this component:

```
<modal :active="active" @close="switchActive('')"></modal>
```

If you want to open one of your modal boxes, you call `switchActive` with the `name` property of your modal box.